# How to call contract function

Tags: contract-development, javascript

I need to call function from my contract.

I got:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: contract.getBadgeOwner is not a function

```
async function a() {
    let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(".......")
//  console.log(contract);
    let currentValue = await contract.getBadgeOwner('withdraw').call();
    console.log(currentValue);
    alert(currentValue);
}
```

This function is for withdraw.

Thanks

Comment: Try `contract.methods.getBadgeOwner('withdraw').call()`. Tron is a separate blockchain from Ethereum and it is unlikely you will have answer to very specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try it:

```
let currentValue = await contract.methods.getBadgeOwner('withdraw').call();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: hi, with this function I can't call in background.
I have in my contract like this:
function deposit() public payable {

}

Function request send.
How can i call function which will trigger deposit from wallet?
If I will use send this I will got: its not sufficient funds, because I can see i calling from contract. My wish is to call deposit function from contract and pay from wallet. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @progy85 As i know `.call()` doesn't change state. If you want to pay from wallet, it will change the state. So, you should use `.send()` instead of `.call()`. Hence, your command returns to `contract.methods.deposit(Arguments if needed).send(Required data if needed);` if your contract defined in a variable as `contract'. Moreover, if you are using a testnet e.g. Ropsten or Ethereum mainnet you should fund your contract's account or wallet account, depending on what you do, enough.